# how to display a page before the home page

Tags: functions, customization

I want to build a wordpress theme in which there is a landing page made by an image and a logo; when the logo is clicked the theme have to go to another page in which there is the navigation bar and other stuff.

Thus, the sequence is this:

1. Landing page (image and logo);
2. Home page (navigation bar, etc..)

My initial idea is to use the `front-page.php` and the `home.php`; is it right? 
Thanks!

Comment: I thought splash pages died in the 90s?

Comment: [Splash pages](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail51.html) will be [the death of your search engine ranking](http://blog.straightnorth.com/top-design-mistakes-that-will-destroy-your-websites-seo/).

Comment: As I always say, died with the dinosaurs, good riddens, and I'm not talking about the dinosaurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I came to conclusion that this splash screen will destroy the website SEO and the usability, so I have decided not to add this kind of page.

Answer (score 1):

1) create one template page on your page-templates dir in landingpage.php with this code

```
page-templates/landingpage.php

<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Landing page
 */
?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                    <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                    the_content();
                                endwhile;
            ?>
                </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->
```

2) Add your page content with image and apply link who display on click

[image]

3) see your landing page on run time and make your css for landing page.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Love the screenshots! What are you using to capture/annotate them? This does leave the issue of logos and other "home" links probably pointing to the static front page, though that is hardly insurmountable.